# rails 3.1, --- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am building a project in rails 3.1, and I am having this message always printed when I do:

```
debug params
```

--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Can any one please explain this error message ?? and why --- !map ??

Comment: Try doing puts params.inspect in the action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't an error message.  The method `debug` converts the object you give it to YAML (a way of serializing objects to a string, not unlike XML or JSON) and prints it out.  The `--- !map` is just part of the YAML format (see http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` is the class name of `params`.

Instead of using `debug`, do

```
p params
```

or

```
puts params.inspect
```

Both will show you nicer output.

Comment: thanks for clarification, i tried p params, but puts params.inspect didn't show any thing